# How to change values in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I need to change values in a nested dictionary. Consider this dictionary:

```
stocks = {
        'name': 'stocks',
        'IBM': 146.48,
        'MSFT': 44.11,
        'CSCO': 25.54,
        'micro': {'name': 'micro', 'age': 1}
    }
```

I need to loop through all the keys and change the values of all the `name` keys.

```
stocks.name
stocks.micro.name
```

These keys need to be changed. But, I will not know which keys to change before hand. So, I'll need to loop through keys and change the values.

**Example**

```
change_keys("name", "test")
```

**Output**

```
{
     'name': 'test',
     'IBM': 146.48,
     'MSFT': 44.11,
     'CSCO': 25.54,
     'micro': {'name': 'test', 'age': 1}
}
```

Comment: "But, I will not know which keys to change before hand" Didn't you say you need to change all the "name" keys?

Comment: @DeepSpace yes thats right. That is just an example because there are multiple keys named 'name'. How would I ensure the correct value is changed?

Comment: Can you add an example of what input/output you expect? It's not clear how you want this dict mutated.

Comment: I gave a sample output

Answer (score 4):

A recursive solution that supports unknown number of nesting levels:

```
def change_key(d, required_key, new_value):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            change_key(v, required_key, new_value)
        if k == required_key:
            d[k] = new_value

stocks = {
    'name': 'stocks',
    'IBM': 146.48,
    'MSFT': 44.11,
    'CSCO': 25.54,
    'micro': {'name': 'micro', 'age': 1}
}


change_key(stocks, 'name', 'new_value')
print(stocks)
#  {'name': 'new_value', 
#  'MSFT': 44.11, 
#  'CSCO': 25.54,
#  'IBM': 146.48,
#  'micro': {'name': 'new_value', 
#            'age': 1}
#  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def changeKeys(d, repl):
    for k,v in zip(d.keys(),d.values()):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            changeKeys(v,repl)
        elif k == "name":
            d[k]= repl
```

Comment: `zip(d.keys(),d.values())`? WTF? `d.items()`!

Comment: I change where the key is 'name' into the value he wants, right?

Comment: @Attersson Not really

Comment: `v= repl` should be `d[k] = repl`, otherwise you're changing `v` which is just the value of `value`, rather than what is stored in the dict (when the item is immutable, like a string)

Comment: Dont change the keys. I just want the values changed. As illustrated in the sample output in the question.

Comment: As @MegaIng points out, `d.items()` gives the same result as the `zip(...)` you have. This is then identical to what I had :)