# How to update the values in a nested dictionary with a for loop?

Tags: python

**I'm trying to update the values (1 and 2) in a nested dict using a for loop.**

```
dict = {"first":{"firstInner":1}, "second":{"secondInner":2}}

for val, inner in dict:
    dict[val][inner] = 3

print(dict)
```

**Desired output:**

```
{"first":{"firstInner":3}, "second":{"secondInner":3}}
```

**Actual output:**

```
line 3, in <module>
    for val, inner in dict:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change values in a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50337256/how-to-change-values-in-a-nested-dictionary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Avoid using `dict` as variable names as it is reserved.**

Iterate over the outer `dict` items and then for every `value` of outer `dict` update the values.

```
dicts = {"first":{"firstInner":1}, "second":{"secondInner":2}}

for key, val in dicts.items():
    for i in val:
        val[i] = 3

print(dicts)
```

```
Output:
 
{'first': {'firstInner': 3}, 'second': {'secondInner': 3}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also found that I needed to add the list() function around the dicts.items(): to have my specific for loop iterate properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so, also **do not use** dict to name the dictionary, its already a reserved name.

```
In [9]: sample
Out[9]: {'first': 3, 'second': 3}

In [10]: sample = {"first":{"firstInner":1}, "second":{"secondInner":2}}

In [11]: for key,value in sample.items():
    ...:     for k in value.keys():
    ...:         value[k] = 3
    ...: 

In [12]: sample
Out[12]: {'first': {'firstInner': 3}, 'second': {'secondInner': 3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to iterate over all the keys within the inner dict, as so:

```py
# For every key on the top level of the dict...
for outer in dict.keys():

    # ... get the keys of the inner dict...
    for inner in dict[outer].keys():

        # ... and set that value to three
        dict[outer][inner] = 3
```

[check out .keys() documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_keys.asp)